# In working out Auto white Balance, what to do if there are multiple sources of the light?

Tags: image-processing

How to do what if the source of the light are more than 1 in Auto White Balance in camera or Image signal Processing?

What should I do ?
AS I know all kinds of algorithms are defined as the source of the light is only one.

Answer (score 0):

White balancing multiple light sources is impossible short of being able to recreate the scene in 3D and identify the colours involved and how they interact with surfaces. Instead, white-balancing is usually carried out using a measurement of the colour temperature of the image, and adjusting the definition of 'white' to balance the blue-amber and magenta-green colours in a scene with multiple lights.

Usually, auto white balance is estimated by taking the colour temperature of the whole scene. You can also try and detect different regions of the scene to balance differently, but this leaves the white-balancing prone to errors that may make it look worse than if the scene were balanced to only one lighting condition.

As an amateur photographer, I've learned that one of the most effective tricks is to white-balance for bright daylight in order to bring out the colour of lighting in a scene. I once woke up to a really nice rusty-red haze during sunrise and took a few photos using this technique. It helps a lot when a camera or device has consistent behaviour. On most cameras, auto-white balance tries to make colours as neutral as possible. To do this, AWB removes any colour tints over the whole image, rather than trying to remove colour tints in small regions of the image.

It's possible to *try* balancing for multiple lights, but the image will look very bland afterward, might not look that great (some portions of an objective being balanced differently from the rest), and will confuse people trying to balance the image. It seems to me a bit more trouble than it is worth.